# How to setup DbUser,AutoCreate,DbGroups in ADFS for Federated access to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, adfs, adfs2.0

I am trying to access redshift database using IAM federation following [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/federate-database-user-authentication-easily-with-iam-and-amazon-redshift/).

In the documentation ,under **"Step1:Set up IdPs and federation"**,it mentions that we need to set three optional attributes like https://redshift.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/DbUser,
https://redshift.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/AutoCreate and 
https://redshift.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/DbGroups

But it is not clear from the documentation that how to add them in case of ADFS IdP .Can any body help me on this ?

Answer (score 2):

You do this via claims rules e.g.

=> issue(type = "https://redshift.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/DbUser", value = "xyz");

Comment: We used following:
// Custom rule AutoCreate:
 => issue(Type = "https://redshift.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/AutoCreate", Value = "true");

// For DBGroups using customer rule with assumption that AD Groups are Redshift-*:
c:[Type == "http://temp/variable", Value =~ "(?i)^Redshift-"]
 => issue(Type = "https://redshift.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/DbGroups", Value = RegExReplace(c.Value, "Redshift-", ""));

// DbUser should use "Send LDAP attributes as claims"